# Cannot find class in package when compiling with javac

Tags: classpath, javac

I have the following structure in my directory :

```
PROJECT
  - classes
      tunnelvisionlabs
          postgresql
              PostgreSqlLexer.class
              PostgreSqlLexerAtnSimulator.class
              PostgreSqlLexerUtils.class
  - lib
      antlr-4-7.jar

  - BasicTest.java
```

In BasicTest.java, i have these imports:

```
package com.tunnelvisionlabs.postgresql.test;

import com.tunnelvisionlabs.postgresql.PostgreSqlLexer;
import com.tunnelvisionlabs.postgresql.PostgreSqlLexerUtils;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Lexer;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Token;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
```

I try to compile with the following command :

```
javac -cp .:./lib/* BasicTests.java
```

I get these errors :

```
BasicTests.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
import com.tunnelvisionlabs.postgresql.PostgreSqlLexer;
                                      ^
  symbol:   class PostgreSqlLexer
  location: package com.tunnelvisionlabs.postgresql
BasicTests.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
import com.tunnelvisionlabs.postgresql.PostgreSqlLexerUtils;
                                      ^
  symbol:   class PostgreSqlLexerUtils
  location: package com.tunnelvisionlabs.postgresql
```

In the PostgreSqlLexer and PostgreSqlLexerUtils classes, i have this package declared at the beginning:

```
package com.tunnelvisionlabs.postgresql;
```

What do i need to do for my program to find these classes ? I tried adding the classes directory in lib and using the same command as before, so that the classpath also contains the classes directory, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: From which exact location are you running `javac`?

Comment: From the PROJECT directory, where BasicTest.java is

Answer (score 0):

If I read your project structure correctly, the source folder where `BasicTest.java` sits is at the same level as the `lib` folder.  If so, then you can using the following `javac` classpath:

```
javac -cp .:lib/* BasicTests.java
            ^^^ lib/ is already where you are calling this
```

Review the following reference answer for more information:

[Including all the jars in a directory within the Java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/including-all-the-jars-in-a-directory-within-the-java-classpath)